# Validation, built-in constraints. I there a way to change message for annotated field depending on what it represents exactly?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am facing trouble with object validation and message customisation. I have a class - a Person. Every person has a name. This field is annotated with a built-in constraint - `@NotNull` and its message - 'Name is required'. Now i have another class - Ticket. In this class there are to fields of type Person. First is called **contact**, second is called **technicalContact**, both are annotated with `@Valid`. Next i have a controller which has a method that accepts a Ticket instance. This method variable is annotated with `@Valid`. So when the method is called and contact person or technical contact person name is null, we get a constraint violation. But in both cases it is the same message.

I would like to distinguish those violations - for example 'Contact person - name is required' when name in contact is null and 'Technical contract person - name is required' when name in technical contact is null.
Is it possible to somehow customise this message if controller method and classes are annotated in presented manner?

Messages are defined in resource file, at constraint level we specify message key. Maybe it is somehow possible to 'change' the resource key if the constraint has some kind of additional variables?

We are using Spring (4.3.19), we use Jersey (2.28) implementation for our REST web services, server is running on Jetty, validation-api (2.0.1).

This is my first post so sorry for any mistakes, I am open to any tips and I can rephrase the question if needed.

```
package pl.example;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Person {

    @NotNull(message = "{validation.constraints.name.notNull}")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

package pl.example;
import javax.validation.Valid;

public class Ticket {

    @Valid
    private Person contact;
    @Valid
    private Person technicalContact;

    public Person getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Person contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public Person getTechnicalContact() {
        return technicalContact;
    }

    public void setTechnicalContact(Person technicalContact) {
        this.technicalContact = technicalContact;
    }
}

package pl.example;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/v1/tickets")
public class TicketResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(@Valid Ticket ticket)
    {
        return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(ticket).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: the code you posted won't compile, it's always better to post the actual code.
Which @Valid are you using? Does it take parameters? You can quite easily create your own annotation, and write your own validation logic/error (message) handling for it

Answer (score 0):

Reading up about Spring validations, I came across the below link which had some useful information (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/error-codes.html). Spring uses JSR-303 Bean validation specifications to resolve errors and error messages. I generates a combination of error codes from the object graph and tries to lookup the error code from the .properties file . All you need to do to solve your problem is to declare a message for each error code and remove the "message" param from the @NotNull annotation. In your .properties file, have entries separately for

```
NotNull.ticket.contact.name = contact name must not be empty
NotNull.ticket.technicalContact.name = Technical contact name must not be empty
```

For a little clarity on the error codes , Below is a list of all error codes autogenerated by spring for the complex object specified in the problem.

```
        "NotNull.ticket.technicalContact.name",
        "NotNull.technicalContact.name",
        "NotNull.name",
        "NotNull.java.lang.String",
        "NotNull"
```